# Choice column sharepoint Ascending not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, choice-field

I have created Sharepoint choice column where i have added country from A to Z name but few countries is not ascending as per there alphabetical order below is the picture of one of country which show some space when i use developer tool but there are no space in my entries does anyone have any idea why this extra space is coming its out of box.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have copied country values from somewhere, and there might be a possibility to have space char or some invisible char. I've pasted countries as plain text from [Github](https://gist.github.com/kalinchernev/486393efcca01623b18d) and seeing no issues sorting.

[image]